# CSS Text in list to right of images is squashed to just one character wide

Tags: css

Hi and thanks in advance,

I am new to this so sorry at the outset if I have trouble explaining. I have a web page and a CSS sheet. The page has three images, one above the other on the left of the contents part of the page and I have a list to hold some text that should display to the right of each image, however the text is squashed up to just one character in width and flows down and overlaps the list items below rather than appear in a single line inline with corresponding image.

Here is the HTML & CSS:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="subscribe">
        <h3>Subscribe!</h3><br></br>
        <ul>
           <li id="phone"><a href="#">Call me via Phone</a></li>
           <li id="email"><a href="#">Get Email Updates</a></li>
           <li id="twitter"><a href="#">Follow us on Twitter</a></li>
           <div style="clear:both"></div>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div> 

#content {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#subscribe {
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#subscribe h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

ul#subscribe li {
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

ul#subscribe li a {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

li#phone {
    list-style: none;
    background: url(images/phone.png) no-repeat; 
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
}

li#email {
    list-style: none;
    background: url(images/email.png) no-repeat; 
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin:0 0 20px 0;
} 

li#twitter {
    list-style: none;
    background: url(images/twitter.png) no-repeat;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    padding-left: 40px; 
    margin:0 0 20px 0; 
}
```

Comment: Its easy to solve if you have fiddle in it.

Comment: you are sure? ul#subscribe -   #subscribe - parent  for ul              http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/rukLf42L/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you gave a width to your li, I made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6qe9r3t9/)
Instead of giving a width to your li you have to resize the background-image

```
li#phone {
list-style: none;
background: url(http://fakeimg.pl/300/) no-repeat;
background-size: 36px 36px; 
padding-left: 40px;
margin:0 0 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, that did the trick.  The only thing is that the images have shrunk a little in in height so how would I compensate for that so they still display as 36px square?